# How to retrieve results outside of NSURLSessionDownloadTask thread?

Tags: ios7, nsurl, nsurlrequest, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

How do I retrieve the results from my `NSURL` file?  In this example, in the `completionHandler`, my results are place in a file called `*localfile`.  I am then parsing the local file with `NSXMLParserDelegate` in a separate `NSObject`.  Everything works great.  however I want and need to the the results of the array `_storeProductArray` for use elsewhere.

For example, the last `NSLog(@"_storeProductArray %@", _storeProductArray);` is empty... I would like to see the results outside of the `NSURLSession` thread.

Thanks

```
    NSDate *startDate1 = [NSDate date];

    NSURL *storeProductURL = [NSURL URLWithString:storeProductLookupResult];

    NSURLRequest *urlRequest                 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:storeProductURL];

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session                    = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];
    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *task           = [session downloadTaskWithRequest:urlRequest
                                                              completionHandler:^(NSURL *localfile, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
                                                {
                                                    if (!error)
                                                    {
                                                        if ([urlRequest.URL isEqual:storeProductURL])
                                                        {
                                                            [productXMLQuery parseDocumentWithURL:localfile];

                                                            _storeProductArray = [productXMLQuery productArray];

                                                            NSDate *endDate1 = [NSDate date];

                                                            NSTimeInterval interval1 = [startDate1 timeIntervalSinceDate:endDate1];
                                                            NSLog(@"1 - Time took: %f", interval1);

                                                            NSLog(@"_storeProductArray %@", _storeProductArray);
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                } ];
    [task resume];

    NSLog(@"_storeProductArray %@", _storeProductArray);
```

Comment: Is _storeProductArray in your interface?

Comment: Yes, @property NSMutableArray *storeProductArray;

Comment: Do you ever initialize the array?

Comment: Yes of corse, otherwise the NSLog in completionNHandler wouldn't work.  I initilziae it in ViewDidLoad     _storeProductArray = [NSMutableArray new];

Comment: Sorry, just double checking so it's not a simple error.  Before the request, try `__block NSArray *array = [NSArray new]; // or some variable name`.  In the block, set array to the value, then after the block, set _storeProductArray to the blockArray variable.

Comment: I added the following: __block NSMutableArray *resultsArray = [NSMutableArray new]; just before the NSDate above.  In the completionHandler I added resultsArray = [productXMLQuery productArray];  after [task resume]; I added     _storeProductArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:resultsArray];
    
    NSLog(@"_storeProductArray %@", _storeProductArray);  results are: 2014-07-10 16:00:45.879 POC[3351:149736] _storeProductArray (
)

Comment: @PaulS. Did you resolve the issue? Unfortunately, I am stuck with the same and is trying to find a way to retrieve the data in this async request.